# Retrieve image url in phtml

Tags: magento2, media

I need to retrieve **image's url** in phtml from **pub/media** dir, the same image that i used in a static wysiwig block retrieved with `{{media url="path/to/image.jpg"}}`.

I know `$block->getViewFileUrl()`, but it takes images from `app/code` or `app/design`.

Is there a same easy way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call Function in Block file,

```
 Class Test{
        protected $storeManager;
        public function __construct(
                \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
              ../////
            ) {
                $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
                ..////
            }

        public function getMediaimg(){
            $folderName = 'cusotomimg';
            $imgname = 'abc.jpg';
            $path = $folderName . '/' . $imgname;
            return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . $path;
        }
    }
```

Now call inside phtml file,

```
   <?php echo $block->getMediaimg(); ?>
```

**Directly using objectmanager,** **this is not recommended way but you can check its using directly in phtml file instead of using objectmanager you can using Block file**

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $om->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$folderName = 'cusotomimg';
$imgname = 'abc.jpg';
$path = $folderName . '/' . $imgname;
echo $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . $path;
```

Answer (score 1):

in block file

```
public function getMediaDirectoryUrl(){

       $media_dir = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
          ->getStore()
          ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

       return $media_dir;
}
```

in phtml file

```
 $block->getMediaDirectoryUrl();
```